# Drawing curved lines in CartoDB?

Tags: postgis, carto, distance-matrix

I am experimenting drawing curved line from Origin to Destination in Cartodb. 
I was able to do so once, however, failed the second and third time.

Could anyone offer me some insights into the following code and help me debug?

I am using CartoDB and start with a table of centroid points for all the countries.

Step 1:CHANGE THE REFERENCE SYSTEM
I used the following code

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext) values ( 953027, 'esri', 53027, '+proj=eqdc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +lat_1=60 +lat_2=60 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs ', 'PROJCS["Sphere_Equidistant_Conic",GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere",DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_Authalic_Sphere",SPHEROID["Sphere",6371000,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Equidistant_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",60],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AUTHORITY["EPSG","53027"]]');
```

Step 2:CREATE THE LINES

```
update world_borders_coarse_2013
set the_geom=
(select st_transform(
  st_segmentize(
    st_makeline(
      st_transform(world_borders_coarse_2013.the_geom,953027),
      st_transform(b.the_geom,953027)),100),4326)
 from world_borders_coarse_2013 b
 where b.name='China'
 )
```

It should give me the curved lines between China to all the other places. However the reality is that I have the "the_geom" column as "line", but nothing shows in the "map view".

Would anyone give me some suggestion to change the code?

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar problem (tried to make curved lines form MULTISTRINGs, see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158203/transform-multilinestrings-to-curves-in-cartodb?noredirect=1#comment234223_158203). You use only minuscule letters in your functions in the SQL statement, have you already tried typing them with uppercase letters, as in e.g. `st_segmentize()` --> `ST_Segmentize()`? Not sure if this is needed (it should actually also work with minuscule letters, right?), but might be worth trying. Also, maybe change the 100 to 100000 (as in the [video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/96235251) (which I suppose you watched). So, maybe this would work:

```
UPDATE world_borders_coarse_2013
SET the_geom=
(SELECT ST_Transform(
    ST_Segmentize(
    ST_MakeLine(
        ST_Transform(world_borders_coarse_2013.the_geom,953027),
        ST_Transform(b.the_geom,953027)),100000),4326)
FROM world_borders_coarse_2013 AS b
WHERE b.name='China'
)
```

And, does "the_geom" contain geometry information? I.e. does it have a "GEO" tag in it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two resources for you,

[What is this PostGIS query doing to show great circle connections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84443/what-is-this-postgis-query-doing-to-show-great-circle-connections/84444#84444)

And a video tutorial: http://vimeo.com/96235251

Comment: This blog posting has the complete great circle solution: https://blog.cartodb.com/jets-and-datelines/