# add geometry to MULTILINESTRING in cartodb

Tags: postgis, carto

I have a table that contains a column with MULTILINESTRINGS (which are the coordinates from two places (i.e. long0,lat0,long1,lat1), like this:

`MULTILINESTRING((97.0253024 4.3685491,8.5618685 47.4524688))`

When I now click on "Map View", nothing gets displayed because "the_geom" in my table is null. My question now is: how can I add geometry information to the column with the MULTILINESTRINGs so that they get displayed on the map? I tried by updating "the_geom" like this:

`UPDATE table_name 
    SET the_geom = 
      ST_SetSRID(column_with_multilines,4326)`

But I only get "undefined rows affected". Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText(column_with_multilines,4326)
```

Docs for `ST_GeomFromText` is [here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Yes, this works for me as well. What I have been trying to do now is to make these lines curved (I know a similar question has already been asked [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98403/drawing-curved-lines-in-cartodb?rq=1)). However, all examples of drawing curved lines concentrate on drawing them from one fix centre point, and not from A to B, C to D, E to F (i.e. the start and end points in my multilines column). Do you know how to make curved lines out of these multiline strings?

Comment: Nice, glad it worked :) for your other question, could you ask another question?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Andy! I posted another question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158203/transform-multilinestrings-to-curves-in-cartodb).